# Term for a "Cartesian union/intersection/difference" of set families

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $A,B$  be two families of sets. What is a term for the following families:

$$C = \{a\cup b|a\in A, b\in B\}$$
$$D = \{a\cap b|a\in A, b\in B\}$$
$$E = \{a\setminus b|a\in A, b\in B\}$$

Since they are similar in nature to Cartesian product, I thought of calling them "Cartesian union", "Cartesian intersection" and "Cartesian difference", respectively. I also thought of denoting them by $C=A \cup^\times B$, $D=A \cap^\times B$, $E=A \setminus^\times B$

Are there more established terms and notations for these operations?

Comment: Interestingly, I don't think there are names for these operations in common use. I wouldn't recommend "Cartesian", however. That adjective in "Cartesian product" is of course inspired by the example of constructing $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ from $\Bbb R$, which raises dimension: the result is a set of ordered pairs, and its members generally aren't/can't be members of the constituent collections. That's not the case for these operations: if for example $A, B \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, then $\{a\cap b\mid a\in A, b\in B\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ also, and similarly for the other operations.

Comment: If you need to use these a lot, you might adopt the notations $\Cup, \Cap$ for the first two (these are \Cup, \Cap resp.) — define them in your proof or paper or whatever. I don't think superscript $\times$ is appropriate, for the same reason I don't think "Cartesian" is a good analogy. As for a notation for $E$, pairwise \setminus, ... dunno :) Perhaps $A \backslash\backslash B$ (\backslash\backslash).